# WKWebView user-agent (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to get the user-agent from WKWebView by using swift,

`let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
useragentlabel.text = webView.configuration.applicationNameForUserAgent`

but it return `Mobile/15E148`, it s can be that the user-agent ?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[self.webView evaluateJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {

 }];
```

The result is userAgent

Comment: yes, thanks, in swift : 
`webViewForUserAgent = WKWebView() // must initialize
        webViewForUserAgent?.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error occured to get userAgent")
                return
            }

            if let unwrappedUserAgent = result as? String {
                UserAgent=unwrappedUserAgent
            } else {
                print("Failed to get userAgent")
            }
        }`

Comment: The very important thing here is when anyone gets "web view is invalidated" error for WKWebView, It might happen that you are initializing WKWebView inside a method and   evaluating above javascript just after that should get invalidated error so the fix for this need to create a globle ref of WKWebview and then evaluate java script inside method then will get correct values without error.

Comment: `result` is null in my case, while `[webView valueForKey:@"userAgent"])` return the value. Why?  I perfer the js script method since `valueForKey` might crash.

Answer (score 22):

Fast, synchronous method with no closures, **Swift 5, iOS 15 and iOS 16 tested**:

```
let UA = WKWebView().value(forKey: "userAgent")
```

would have UA have (optional value) of:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_5 like Mac OS X)
> AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148

for iOS 13.5 in iPhone XS Simulator

This has passed the appstore review.

Comment: So much nicer than the other answers using asynchronous JS!

Comment: That's great, thanks!
Here is the Objective-C version if someone still needs it too:
`NSString *userAgent = [[WKWebView new] valueForKey:@"userAgent"];`

Comment: Please note that the solution above uses undocumented API, therefore it can stop working at any time. Executing JS is less convenient, but seems to be more reliable.

Answer (score -8):

This gets the user agent:

```
let userAgent = webView.customUserAgent!
```

Comment: If no custom user agent string has been set, this is set to nil.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414950-customuseragent

Comment: This will not give default values for user agents.