# How to get user agent using swift without using the deprecated WebView

Tags: ios, swift

I need to get the user agent. 
I used to get it using UIWebView but it's deprecated now.

```
let userAgent = UIWebView().stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "navigator.userAgent")!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WKWebView user-agent (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337691/wkwebview-user-agent-swift)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can get the `userAgent` using below snippet of code,

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{
 
    var WKwebView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getUserAgent()
    }
    
    func getUserAgent() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        WKwebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        WKwebView.evaluateJavaScript(
            "navigator.userAgent", 
            completionHandler: { (result, error) in
                debugPrint(result as Any)
                debugPrint(error as Any)

                if let unwrappedUserAgent = result as? String {
                    print("userAgent: \(unwrappedUserAgent)")
                } else {
                    print("failed to get the user agent")
                }
            }
        )
    }    
}
```

> **Output** : userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac
> OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148

Comment: I can't get this to work. I just get an error back: ```"JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type"```

Comment: The very important thing here is when anyone gets "web view is invalidated" error for WKWebView, It might happen that you are initializing WKWebView inside a method and evaluating the above javascript just after that should get an invalidated error so the fix for this needs to create a global ref of WKWebview and then evaluate javascript inside method then will get correct values without error.
Credits: Sagar Daundkar

Answer (score 7):

It's better to use this one fragment of code.

```
 let userAgent = WKWebView().value(forKey: "userAgent")
```

Answer (score 6):

Use WebKit instead.

```
import WebKit

let webView = WKWebView()
webView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { (result, error) in
    print(result as! String)
}

// Output 
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 13_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148
```

Comment: Solves my loading problem.

Answer (score 2):

The synchronous function provided by Haiiro is more practical, here is the objective-c version.

```
NSString *userAgent = [[[WKWebView alloc] init] valueForKey:@"userAgent"];
```